# Circle Array Modifier for face rotation

Tags: python

I know how to add a circular array modifier, it is shown e.g. in a video like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjFb0xFoLk

But what I want to do is to create such a circular array that is snapped to a face of an object - so that the whole array is rotated / aligned to the rotation of the face.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**3 Vertex Parenting**

[image]

- Assume you have set up the empty and object with array modifier as
  explained in [youtube video in question](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whjFb0xFoLk).

  In example I have a cone with array modifier controlled by an empty
  displayed as axis.
- For simplicity sake added a 3 vertex filled circle.  It has one face.
  In edit mode select 3 vertices of the face to parent empty to.
- In object mode, select the empty, then the mesh and choose
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> Parent Vertex (**T**riangle)

  The array empty will now be rotated when the face rotates.
- This may be difficult to set up depending on the alignment of the
  face.  A similar method could be done via the copy rotation
  constraint on the empty, using the face object as a target and the vertices of the face in a vertex group as the subtarget.

[image]
*In this setup only the global Y rotation of the empty is effected by the rotation of our target face*